# Cognos Report on SharePoint data

Tags: bi

Anyone have ideas on how to create a Cognos package on SharePoint 2010 data?  I'm looking to create a Cognos report based off a SharePoint list.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if Cognos is capable of accessing RESTful data sources, here's how to do so in SharePoint 2010: http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/accessing-sharepoint-2010-lists-using.html

SharePoint 2013 now includes OData API for accessing list data: http://www.mindsharp.com/blog/2012/07/sharepoints-rest-an-odata-overview/